# PHP Serilization fails in PHP 5.5 but not PHP 5.3

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to troubleshoot a serialization problem and want to find out more about the following:

```
if ($result === false && serialize(false) !== $postResult)
```

I'm trying to break this up into litle chunks to solve it.

```
if ($result === false)
{
throw new ClientException("the result is false ===");
}
```

Why will this throw an exception? I don't understand what this relates to. Does false have a natural state for example, no value?

Thank you for the answers, the further information is as follows:

The $result contains a serialized array of media data. If I var_dump($result), I see the array but it fails the IF statement above and I'm not sure why.

I have two bits of the same software. Two versions of PHP, 5.3 and 5.5.

I can var_dump the array and everything looks great on both versions but 5.3 passes the IF statement and 5.5 fails.

Everything else works before that except it maybe failing here:

```
$result = unserialize($postResult);
```

The actual sequence being:

```
$result = unserialize($postResult);

if ($result === false && serialize(false) !== $postResult)

{
throw new ClientException("failed to unserialize server result - the result is as follows:" . "Error start:". print_r($error,true). ":Error end" . "RESULT (After serialize): " . print_r($result,true) . "PARAMS: " . print_r($params,true) . "Files: " . print_r($files,true) . "URL " . print_r($url,true) . "Pre result: " . print_r($postResult,true) .":", ClientException::ERROR_UNSERIALIZE_FAILED);
            }
```

Comment: Uhm, `serialize(false) !== $postResult` should be `serialize(false) === $postResult`. And you should show us what $result is.

Comment: If you don't initialize `$result`, its default value will be `NULL`, which is not `=== false`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question _does false have a natural state?_ `false` is a specific value.

Comment: `false` is the boolean value false. `===` is the type safe comparison operator. if `($result === false) ` evaluates to true, your `$result` is set to `false` somewhere before. Is that what you were wondering? Most likely there is something along the way to get your `$result` that fails now, but didn't fail on your setup before.